# VSTO Document-Level customization executing built-in commands

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I am creating a C# Document-Level customization for word. How can I put some of the existing commands (paragraph keep lines together etc) onto a custom ribbon bar? Is it also possible to execute commands programatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ExecuteMso method of the CommandBars class to execute built-in commands programmatically.

If you need to place built-in controls on a custom tab you need to specify the idMso value of the built-in control. You can read more about the Ribbon UI (aka Fluent UI) in the following series of articles in MSDN:

1. [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
2. [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
3. [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)